# Слитно или через дефис: "видео-консультация" или "видеоконсультация"?

Tags: орфография, слитно-дефис

Здравствуйте! Как правильно: "видео-консультация" или "видеоконсультация"?

Answer (score 2):

Видеоконсультация. 
Сложные слова с первой иноязычной  частью, кончающейся на гласную, пишутся слитно.

• с конечным о : авто-, агро-, астро-, аудио-, аэро-, баро-, бензо-, био-, вело-, вибро-, видео-, гекто-, гелио-, гео-, гетеро-, гидро-, гомо-, дендро-, зоо-, изо-, кило-, кино-, космо-, макро-, метео-, микро-, моно-, мото-, невро-, нейро-, нео-, орто-, палео-, пиро-, пневмо-, порно-, психо-, радио-, ретро-, сейсмо-, социо-, спектро-, стерео-, термо-, турбо-, фито-, фоно-, фото-, эвако-, экзо-, эко-, электро-, эндо-, энерго-

Причем если этих корней будет несколько, все равно пишем слитно. Например, автомотовеломагазин.

Answer (score 1):

[@Ларf](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f) всё правильно сказал, но есть ещё случай, когда появляется союз, тогда пишется так: *"Вчера проводились авто- и велогонки".*

Comment: Верное дополнение. Немного в сторону - я, когда регистрировалась, нечаянно перешла на английский шрифт. Вместо Лара получилось Ларf. Так и осталось.

Comment: Должно быть Лаза?

Comment: Извините, что я принял вас за особу мужского пола.

Comment: Простите за вопрос, если не хотите - не отвечайте. В Вашем профиле указан возраст 87 лет. Это не опечатка?

Comment: Это не опечатка, это фальсификация данных.