# "Фоторедакция". Писать слитно, раздельно или через дефис?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно-дефис

Как правильно писать:
1. Слитно: фоторедакция.
2. Через дефис: фото-редакция.
3. Или раздельно: фото редакция?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слитно. Подобный вопрос был совсем недавно.[Читайте здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5533/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)